# Affix a div to the browser on scroll and prevent overflowing from parent div

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to find a way to have a div affix to the top of a users browser as they scroll *past* the div but this should not pass the parent div. I have created a basic gif for the concept.

Current markup:

```css
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.container {
        width:100%;
        float:left;
        height:800px;
        background:blue;
    }
    .overlay {
        width:50%;
        height:800px;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        padding:1em;
        background:red;
        display:block;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .overlay-content {
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background:white;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-content">
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Example of desired functionality]

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should put the overlay with position sticky

```
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
```

and add to the conteiner

```
position:relative;
```

Comment: That would stick the overlay, not the overlay content though?

Comment: Sorry you are correct try putting the sticky position to the overlay content!

Comment: sticky is deprecated, use fixed.

Comment: fixed-sticky is deprecated https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky

Answer (score -1):

On window scroll, some calculation will indicate when you reach the bottom edge, just toggle(add/remove) Class "stick" at the right time.

CSS:

```
.stick {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: If I used fixed on the overlay content and relative on the overlay I am unable to see the overlay content

Comment: Work with z-index to layer the elements properly. relative will not be required as the fixed element will not be placed relative to it.

Comment: Are you able to provide a working js fiddle? I cannot seem to get this to work